# Ubuntu "Wubildr.mbr is missing or contains errors."

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7, wubi, uefi

I want to get Ubuntu on my laptop (HP Pavilion) but every time I try to install it using Wubi, I get this error:

```
Wubildr is missing or contains errors.
```

What could be the problem?

I had Ubuntu on this laptop before so it can't be anything with UEFI. I also even tried a full installation. It would either come up with the same error or this:

```
Please insert a bootable medium. Press any key to reboot.
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately wubi is no longer supported and the absolute most reliable way to install is by booting a livecd/usb that you have burned. On windows 8 based systems wubi has been proven to not work at all.

Comment: you are completely welcome.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I tried a DVD and USB running Ubuntu 14.04 but I still got the same error? (Sorry If im posting this in the wrong place, im new to the forums!)

Comment: did you boot into them? or run wubi?

Comment: I booted into it.

Comment: when did you get the error?

Comment: Right after I installed ubuntu. When I pressed "restart" it booted into that error.

Comment: have you tried redownloading the iso?

Comment: Yes, I have tried Ubuntu 12.04, Ubuntu 14.04, and Ubuntu 9.04.

Comment: and all of them have thrown that error when you install from a full booted live session?

Comment: Yep. or the error: Please insert a bootable medium. Press any key to reboot.

Comment: are you trying to dual boot?

Comment: Nope. I was not trying to dual boot.

Comment: what does your partition layout look like? and when you boot the system do you get a purpleish screen with a man and a keyboard at the bottom? or do you get a menu?

Comment: I get a message from Windows Boot Manager I think.